# Fail to install kivy with pip

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to install kivy 1.11.1 by the official site, but this error occurred:`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477...` I searched on another question on the stack overflow and it said that is a bug with recent versions of kivy:

[Failed to install the module kivy in windows with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63085565/failed-to-install-the-module-kivy-in-windows-with-pip)

Then I tried to install the kivy 1.10 but this error occurred:  `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1` , every thing I tried to fix goes wrong.

I checked the dependencies and they are fully correct, made a new virtualenv called kivy and deleted the other and I already installed Cython, nothing worked.
What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As reported the before in https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6687. Download the recent wheel from https://kivy.org/downloads/ci/win/kivy/
and install via the following code:

`python -m pip install CHANGE_THIS_TO_THE_FILE_NAME.whl`

Check if you need win32 or 64.

Comment: I downloaded the first wheel on the list of https://kivy.org/downloads/ci/win/kivy/  and installed, but ERROR: Kivy-2.0.0rc3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. :(

Comment: I deleted and downloaded again and now this apeare WARNING: Requirement 'Kivy-2.0.0rc3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist